# ReacTran 2D Diffusion model with non-conformable arrays error in R, matrix and setup.grid.1D and setup.grid.2D

Tags: r, 2d

I am trying to model diffusion in 2D in R with the diffusion rate being dependent on the density, y. I have completed this model in 1D, but trying to change it 2D it keep getting the error code:

```
    Error in -VF.grid$x.int * D.grid$x.int * diff(rbind(C.x.up, C, C.x.down, non-conformable arrays
```

I have no data, as it is a simulation. My code is as follows;

```
library(ReacTran)

N     <- 50          # number of grid cells
Nx  <-50
Ny  <-50
XX    <- 10           # total size
dy    <- dx <- XX/N  # grid size
Dy    <- Dx <- 0.1   # diffusion coeff, X- and Y-direction
r     <- 0.005       # growth rate
ini   <- 10           # initial value at x=0
N2  <- ceiling(N/2)
K <- 100        #Carrying Capacity
A0<- 2      #pop ini size


x.grid    <- setup.grid.1D(x.up = 0, x.down = 1, N = N)
y.grid    <- setup.grid.1D(x.up = 0, x.down = 1, N = N)
grid2D    <- setup.grid.2D(x.grid, y.grid)

D.grid    <- setup.prop.2D(value = Dx, y.value = Dy, grid = grid2D)     #diffusion coefficient on cell interfaces
v.grid    <- setup.prop.2D(value = 0, y.value=0, grid = grid2D) #advection velocity
A.grid    <- setup.prop.2D(value = 1, y.value=1, grid = grid2D) #interface area
AFDW.grid <- setup.prop.2D(value = 0, y.value=0, grid = grid2D) #advction weight difference
VF.grid   <- setup.prop.2D(value = 0, y.value=1, grid = grid2D) #volume fraction

# The model equations - using the grids

Diff2Db <- function (t, y, parms)  {

   U <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = N, data = y)

   dCONC <- tran.2D(C = y, C.x.up=0, C.x.down=0,
    C.y.up=0, C.y.down=0,
    grid = grid2D, D.grid = D.grid, 
    D.x=(y-1)^2 + 1, D.y=(y-1)^2 + 1, dx=dx, dy=dy,
    A.grid = A.grid, 
    VF.grid = VF.grid, AFDW.grid = AFDW.grid, v.grid = v.grid
    )$dC 
        return (list(dCONC))
}

# initial condition: 0 everywhere, except in central point
y <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = N, data = 0)
y[N2,N2] <- ini  # initial concentration in the central point...

times <- 0:8
outb <- ode.2D (y = y, func = Diff2Db, t = times, parms = NULL,
                dim = c(49, N), lrw = 160000)
```

I am out of ideas to try to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance